# Couldn't we use "du coup" in written French?

Tags: usage, locutions, registre

I ever heard from my French teacher that "du coup" is used only for spoken usage, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: ...and _du coup_, you're not so sure about it? ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Du coup* is widely used in written French, but you will find that some people follow the recommandation of the Académie Française of not using it as a synonym of *donc* and only use it in the sense of *aussitôt*. But as we can see in the example taken from Zola (below) the barrier between the two meanings is sometimes very thin.

My point of view is that language is a living thing, it evolves and we find numerous instances of *du coup* used in the sense of *donc* in very good writings.

---

Il y a autour de l'expression « du coup » une polémique qui se trouve résumée  dans cet article de 2005 : «Du coup». Un vilain tic de langage © [Le Télégramme](http://www.letelegramme.fr/france/du-coup-un-vilain-tic-de-langage-09-09-2015-10766658.php#c1WxUP4CCHA5PIpM.99)
Cet article reflète autant l'usage de l'expression à l'oral qu'à l'écrit.

[L'Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/du-coup-au-sens-de-de-ce-fait) recommande de ne garder l'usage de l'expression que dans son sens premier d'« aussitôt » et décourage l'emploi de « du coup » pour exprimer la conséquence :

> La locution adverbiale *du coup* a d’abord été employée au sens propre : *Un poing le frappa et il tomba assommé du coup*. Par la suite, on a pu l’utiliser pour introduire la conséquence d’un évènement : *Un pneu a éclaté et du coup la voiture a dérapé*. Mais, ainsi que le dit *Le Bon Usage*, il exprime « l’idée d’une cause agissant brusquement », et à sa valeur consécutive s’ajoute donc une valeur temporelle traduisant une quasi-simultanéité. *Du coup* est alors très proche d’*aussitôt*. On ne peut donc pas employer systématiquement *du coup*, ainsi qu’on l’entend souvent, en lieu et place de *donc*, *de ce fait*, ou *par conséquent*. On évitera également de faire de du coup un simple adverbe de discours sans sens particulier.

Ce n'est ni la première, ni la dernière fois sans doute, que des  puristes s'offusquent de l’évolution de la langue. L'usage nous montre que « du coup » est aussi présent dans la langue orale que dans la langue écrite, et dans des écrits dont le style ne saurait être qualifié de familier.

> L'air entrait par bouffées glaciales, tous deux s'emportaient, en soutenant chacun l'exactitude de ses renseignements, lorsque des cris et des larmes éclatèrent. C'était, dans son berceau, Estelle que le froid contrariait.
>   Du coup, Maheu se réveilla. (Émile Zola, [*Germinal*](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/Visualiseur?Destination=Gallica&O=NUMM-101504))
>
> les hasards d'une conversation avec sa mère l'amenèrent à en faire l'aveu, et le lièrent ainsi à une fantaisie de gosse, qu'il eût si facilement abandonnée, qu'il était du coup dans l'obligation de poursuivre. (Aragon, *Les Beaux quartiers*,1936, p. 239. Exemple du [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/coup), qui d'ailleurs ne qualifie pas l'expression de familière).
>
> Dans sa fonction verticale le signe renvoie à des entités moins vastes, plus concrétisée que le symbole – ce sont des universaux RÉIFIÉS, devenus OBJETS au sens fort du mot; or, relationnée dans une structure de signe, l'entité en question (le phénomène, ou le personnage) est, du coup, transcendentalisée, élevée au rang d'une unité théologique. (Julia Kristeva, [*Le Texte du Roman: Approche sémiologique d'une structure discursive transformationnelle*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mfEgAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&dq=%22du%20coup%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtib3EnqbTAhXFWhoKHYbhCHwQ6AEIUzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22du%20coup%22&f=false))
>
> Ce profit est une meilleure compréhension des valeurs intrinsèques de l'œuvre, et, du coup, une interprétation plus poussée de ses rapports externes. (Guy Demerson, *[Louise Labé, les voix du lyrisme](https://books.google.fr/books?id=g1twRiFcypEC&pg=PA107&dq=%22du%20coup%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV7IvJoKbTAhWGbRQKHSEuDcc4ChDoAQgyMAM#v=onepage&q=%22du%20coup%22&f=false)*)
>
> Du coup le sublime retombe. L’aura qui entourait le sacrifice du père Goriot s’efface, et il ne reste plus de son sacrifice que l’image d’une servitude volontaire, d’une domesticité, quand le maître de la domus n’est plus qu’une sorte d’animal domestique, de « toutou » manipulé. ( [Le sublime et le grotesque chez Balzac : l’exemple du « Père Goriot »](http://www.cairn.info/revue-l-annee-balzacienne-2001-1-page-31.html), par [Pierre Brunel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Brunel), paru dans une revue universitaire.)

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea why someone would say that, at least for its meaning (and I know of no others) of "as such, by the same token".

It's a perfectly valid locution at most language levels. It's in the [*Trésor de la Langue Française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/coup) and the [Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/coup) dictionaries, and covered in Grevisse (*Bon Usage*, 14th ed. §1006 f.) with no usage notes anywhere.

Comment: To support your answer the TLF has a sentence form Louis Aragon to illustrate the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

"Du coup" is only for spoken usage. But it can be used quite informally in a private message for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it is only for spoken language, but this is somehow familiar.

So, IMHO, it depends of the context.

But, indeed, we tend to use it more often when we talk ... at least in Belgium.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, 'du coup' is only spoken, you should not write this down.

**EDIT**
Finding it on 'very good books' does not mean it is commonly accepted sorry. Du coup is used, in the spoken language, mainly as the consequence of something like 'which leads to', 'so', 'consequently'. My point is that if you write an application to a job and you use it, someone might find you way too friendly.

Comment: What? Where did you get that idea? Give me a citation!

Comment: Would you use on a job application? On a thesis dissertation? I hardly think so...Personnaly see that it sounds way to _friendly_...

Comment: Numerous examples of *du coup* found in googlebooks from French speaking writers, in all sorts of writings, novels, academic & institutional  writings, of course I only selected *du coup* as meaning *à la suite de quoi*, and eliminated *coup* as "blow" in my search.

Comment: Incidentally, "which leads to" and "consequently" are both fairly elevated in English. :)