# "Du coup" : Origine, registre et façons de l'éviter

Tags: étymologie, locutions, synonymes, régionalismes, registre

D'où vient l'emploi à peu près "passe-partout" (qui me frappe bien que je sois un locuteur non natif du français) de la locution *du coup* ?
Quel est son registre ? Ayant observé que trop d'étudiants l'emploient durant leurs discours, les échanges avec les enseignants, leurs exposés (un étudiant l'a employé aujourd'hui dix (!) fois lors d'une présentation d'une demi-heure) je me pose la question suivante : avec quels mots et quelles locutions peut-on l'éviter dans les contextes variés de son utilisation ? Dernière question, cette locution est-elle employée partout en France où est-elle une particularité du parler du sud de la France ?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25451/couldnt-we-use-du-coup-in-written-french

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Du coup, voici un thread encore plus vieux:-)! https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/usage-of-du-coup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> D'où vient l'emploi à peu près "passe-partout" (qui me frappe bien que je sois un locuteur non natif du français) de la locution du coup ?

Ce tic est une mode, il y en a d'autres.

Certaines durent, d'autres pas. Certaines finissent par se lexicaliser, d'autres par se ringardiser.

> Quel est son registre ?

Un registre genre large spectre, du coup, on la trouve partout, voilà.

> Ayant observé que trop d'étudiants l'emploient durant leurs discours,

C'est grave trop vrai, j'avoue.

> avec quels mots et quelles locutions peut-on l'éviter dans les contextes variés de son utilisation ?

Tu peux dire *donc* ou *en conséquence* à la place, mais il risque d'y en avoir trop, des *donc* et des *en conséquence* si tu n'y prends pas garde, alors du coup, le mieux, c'est peut-être tout simplement de la supprimer, cette expression, si elle t'ennuie, tu vois, sans affecter la signification du discours. Quant à vouloir l'éradiquer chez les autres, la cause est perdue d'avance.

> Dernière question, cette locution est-elle employée partout en France où est-elle une particularité du parler du sud de la France ?

On l'entend grave partout, j'dis ça, j'dis rien...

Voili-voilou.

Comment: Je suis à peu près sûr qu'aucun jeune ne dit "grave partout", pour la même raison qu'on ne dit pas "très partout". Même chose avec "grave trop vrai" (oui c'est pas sensé être sérieux, je sais ^^)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Si si, *grave* a un spectre d'utilisation plus large que *très*. *Grave partout* existe, je l'ai entendu. Je viens même d'en trouver un exemple dans un forum et pas par quelqu'un de si jeune que ça (36 ans): *et vive le graissage chinois !!!! à moin que j'me trompe **y'en a grave partout** et 3 tonne, moi j'en met pas autant* Pareil pour [*grave trop vrai*](https://twitter.com/SarahkTraiteur/status/742996234881863681)

Answer (score 1):

Dans son utilisation correcte, le registre de cette locution est celui de la langue courante écrite et parlée.

L'origine, quant à la logique des mots, est tout simplement le combat à mains nues ou armées d'objets contondants. Je ne sais rien quant à son introduction dans le langage (période, circonstances).

La meilleure façon **d'éviter son emploi incorrect** est de bien connaitre son contexte d'utilisation de sorte à identifier sans erreur si le contexte donné convient ou non et ainsi de fournir une locution appropriée.

Elle est employée à tort et à travers dans toute la France et il serait surprenant qu'elle ne le soit pas ailleurs aussi.

---

On trouve une définition de cette locution dans le TLFi, mais elle ne correspond pas très bien à ce que l'on peut attendre de l'emploi correct de la locution en cela qu'elle spécifie l'idée de conséquence mais pas celle du contexte demandé dans lequel cette conséquence s'ensuit.

> (TLFi) À la suite de quoi

Au lieu de cette définition, celle du dictionnaire de l'Académie s'impose, mais ce n'est pas celle qui justifie l'emploi de la locution dans toutes les bouches de nos jours.

Les explication données par l'organe linguistique du [Figaro](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/09/22/37003-20170922ARTFIG00008-du-coup-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php) expliquent l'essentiel à propos de cette locution et du malaise qui résulte de son emploi.

> ORTHOGRAPHE - La locution a peu à peu pris le pas dans nos conversations. Jusqu'à devenir un véritable tic de langage chez certains. À tort. Pourquoi est-elle incorrecte ? Comment éviter l'impair ? Le Figaro analyse la question.
>   C'est ce qui s'appelle une expression coup-de-poing. Avec elle, toutes les conjonctions adverbiales et locutions sont tombées. Assommées. «Du coup» s'est littéralement imposé. Partout. «On ne sort pas ce soir. On fait quoi du coup?», «il ne veut pas manger de salade, du coup je fais des haricots», etc. Les exemples sont nombreux et éloquents. Mais comment expliquer l'omniprésence de cette formule dans nos conversations? Que disait-on avant? Le Figaro fait le point.
>   À l'origine l'expression n'est pas incorrecte. Ainsi que nous le rappelle l'Académie française, «du coup» peut s'employer au sens propre. Exemple: «Un poing le frappa et il tomba assommé du coup.» On la retrouve en outre, correctement utilisée pour exprimer la conséquence, **«l'idée d'une cause agissant brusquement»**. Exemple: «Son moteur a explosé et du coup sa voiture a pris feu.» La locution, notent les sages, a pour équivalent sémantique la formule «aussitôt». En dehors de ces deux sens, «du coup» est incorrect et son emploi relève de l'abus de langage. 
>   Ainsi est-il un non-sens de vouloir donner à la locution le rôle d'adverbe. On ne peut donc pas en faire un synonyme de «donc», «de ce fait», «par conséquent», etc. Formules pour leur part correctes et regrettablement évacuées au profit d'un français toujours plus rétréci et simplifié…

L'idée de **cause agissant brusquement** est l'essentiel de ce qu'implique la locution adverbiale «du coup». Plus précisément, il est impliqué que l'action brusque, qui en fait n'a pas à être si brusque qu'inhabituelle, constitue un imprévu, un évènement qui bouleverse plus ou moins des plans, des habitudes et qui a une conséquence non moins inhabituelle, laquelle est introduite par « du coup ».

- Alors qu'elle prenait un verre au bar, il lui a appris la nouvelle de la mort de leur voisin dans un accident, ce qui la choqua profondément ; du coup elle a oublié ses clés sur le comptoir.
- Le gardien s'est fait voler ses clés ; du coup tout le dortoir va manquer une heure de cours avant qu'un serrurier vienne ouvrir la porte.
- Elle m'a fait des histoires à n'en plus finir, m'a presque insulté et menacé de ne plus avoir à faire à nos services… du coup je lui ai supprimé la prime qui avait été prévue.
- La loi a changé d'une façon que vous ne pouviez prévoir et du coup tous ces avantages qui vous permettaient de voyager librement sont supprimés.
- Les nouvelles mesure de taxation favorisent incroyablement les personnes dans notre créneau de revenu ; du coup nous nous retrouvons avec cinq mille euros de plus dans le budget annuel, j'ai fait les calculs ; tu aurais jamais pu croire à quelque chose comme ça ?