# Signification of the quote "Quand les peuples cessent d'estimer, ils cessent d'obéir"

Tags: sens

This seems to be « la devise » of [Rivarol](https://www.rivarol.com/), a conservative magazine in France. The quote

> Quand les peuples cessent d'estimer, ils cessent d'obéir

is at the top of their home page.

I don't understand the idea communicated. To me it reads like:

"When people stop thinking, they stop obeying."

What is the meaning? Qu'est que ça veut dire ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est une citation d'Antoine Rivarol, de son vrai nom Antoine Rivaroli (23 juin 1753 - 11 avril 1801) qui est un écrivain français, journaliste royaliste, essayiste et pamphlétaire. La citation complète est :

> Quand les peuples cessent d'estimer, ils cessent d'obéir. Règle
>   générale : les nations que les rois assemblent ou consultent
>   commencent par des vœux et finissent par des volontés.

Voici comment l'[auteur lui-même](https://books.google.fr/books?id=T75CAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=Quand%20les%20peuples%20cessent%20d%27estimer,%20ils%20cessent%20d%27ob%C3%A9ir.%20R%C3%A8gle%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale%20:%20les%20nations%20que%20les%20rois%20assemblent%20ou%20consultent%20commencent%20par%20des%20voeux%20et%20finissent%20par%20des%20volont%C3%A9s.&source=bl&ots=eAMON5eCRM&sig=ACfU3U1GpTOw5OPXfhFxobwAvJ4prfGCxQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU4bnHg-7gAhW7ThUIHYefDt0Q6AEwBXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=Quand%20les%20peuples%20cessent%20d'estimer%2C%20ils%20cessent%20d'ob%C3%A9ir.%20R%C3%A8gle%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale%20%3A%20les%20nations%20que%20les%20rois%20assemblent%20ou%20consultent%20commencent%20par%20des%20voeux%20et%20finissent%20par%20des%20volont%C3%A9s.&f=false) aborde cette idée.

[image]

Voici sa biographie : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_de_Rivarol

Je pense que l'auteur veut dire :

> Quand les peuples cessent d'apprécier (le roi ?)/de montrer du respect (au roi ?), ils cessent d'obéir (au roi ?)

Le lemme du TLFi supporte ce point de vue

> **B [Avec une valorisation affective] Accorder de l'estime (cf. ce mot B), apprécier positivement une personne ou une chose qui mérite
>   l'admiration, le respect intellectuel ou moral.**

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/estimer

Comment: Merci, que veux-tu dire par <<Du coup>> (au debut de ton reponse)?

Comment: @timwiz Vois ici https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/usage-of-du-coup et https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25451/couldnt-we-use-du-coup-in-written-french et https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33446/du-coup-origine-registre-et-fa%C3%A7ons-de-l%C3%A9viter/33452#33452

Answer (score 4):

Une plus grande partie du  passage où se trouve la citation

« Quand les peuples cessent d'estimer, ils cessent d'obéir. Règle générale : les nations que les rois assemblent ou consultent commencent par des vœux et finissent par des volontés. »

La première partie de cette remarque est l'expression d'une réalité qui coule presque de source dans le contexte de la politique ; « estimer » doit être pris dans le sens suivant de « être d'accord, de respecter les principes politiques avancés, d'honorer ceux qui les avancent (pour cette raison même que ces principes sont trouvés respectables) ». De cet état de chose en ce qui concerne le rapport entre le peuple et l'autorité, quelle qu'elle soit, à la notion que le peuple obéit, il n'y a qu'un pas :   son estime est quasiment un assentiment, un acquiescement au directives qui émanent de l'autorité selon les principes reconnus ; donc cette estime va de pair avec l'obéissance du peuple ;  lorsque elle disparait, c'est pratiquement  la contrainte d'obéir qui disparait ; c'est le fondement de l'obéissance qui disparait.

On pourrait traduire de la façon suivante ;

- When a people loses its esteem, it stops obeying.
- When a people stops paying obeisance, it stops obeying.

Answer (score 2):

*Estimer* has mutiple meanings. The one that seems to make more sense in this quote is the meaning of "to have a good opinion of someone, to have a lot of respect for someone, to look up to someone".

The quote means then:

> When peoples stop showing some respect, they stop obeying.

This is then coherent with the conservative, monarchist line of thinking of the author.

Comment: This English phrasing doesn't sound quite right. I'm afraid it becomes tautological. I'd suggest “start losing respect”, or something entirely different.