# Tournure de phrase

Tags: phrase

Est-il possible de s'exprimer de la manière suivante en français? Surtout je me demande si la position de "à la place" et "du coup" est adéquate.

> Elle est seulement à quelques mètres de lui alors il se prépare à lui serrer la main. Quand elle l'embrasse sur les deux joues **à la place**, il est **du coup** un peu surpris.

Comment: Surtout je me demande si la position de "à la place" et "du coup" est adéquate dans la deuxième phrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*À la place* peut être utilisé comme ça mais je trouve qu'il serait mieux en début de phrase :

> A la place, elle l'embrasse...

*Du coup* est une expression parfois controversée dans cet usage<sup>1</sup>. Ici aussi, le début de phrase me semble beaucoup plus idiomatique (*du coup* est incompatible avec *quand*<sup>2</sup>):

> Elle l'embrasse sur les deux joues. Du coup, il est un peu surpris.

Si j'avais a réécrire ces deux phrase, je n'utiliserais ni *à la place* qui est assez implicite, ni *du coup* :

> Elle n'est plus qu'à quelques mètres de lui alors il se prépare (ou il s'apprête) à lui serrer la main. Quand elle l'embrasse sur les deux joues, il est un peu surpris.

<sup>1</sup>   <sub>Questions relatives à *du coup* :

[Usage of “du coup”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2958)

[Couldn't we use "du coup" in written French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25451)

["Du coup" : Origine, registre et façons de l'éviter](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33446)</sub>

<sup>2</sup>  <sub>On peut dire: *Du coup, il est surpris quand elle l'embrasse...* mais pas *Quand elle l'embrasse du coup il est surpris...*</sub>